# Big O complexity class of (n+1) squared

Tags: analysis, computational-complexity

I have the following statement:

$(n+1)^2 = $

- $n^2+O(n^{7/8})$
- $n^2+\Theta(n^{1/2})$
- $n^2+o(n^{3/4})$
- None of these.

I'm a bit confused, can I just solve it like a usual equation? Something in the lines of..

$(n+1)^2=n^2+x$

$n^2+2n+1=n^2+x$

$2n + 1 = x$

Now basically I should find the suitable complexity class for $2n$ which can't be found from the list. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Looks correct to me.